# While/Else Recheck the condition and loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
def check(onen,twon,threen,fourn,fiven):
while ((onen != twon) and (onen != threen) and (onen != fourn) and (onen != fiven)):
    return onen
else:
    onen = random.randint(1,45)
```

I'd like to ask how to make it like this:

```
def check(onen,twon,threen,fourn,fiven):
while ((onen != twon) and (onen != threen) and (onen != fourn) and (onen != fiven)):
    return onen
else:
    onen = random.randint(1,45)
        (check the condition on while again)
```

I want to make this loop: if the condition is false, check and check again until it's true.

Comment: `while`-`else` exists, but it is not very common.

Comment: then when should the loop end? If you want to make it loop forever, remove else.

Comment: Your question is not very clear because you use a `return` in both legs of the `while` statement. This means that as soon as either `return` is encountered, it leaves the function. No looping occurs. It seems your `while` is in fact just an `if` - `else`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Give some context on `something`?

Comment: @ZeeshanHyder It won't loop for ever, `return` terminates the function

Comment: I Edited it with the real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have it backwards. Try this:

```
while not condition:
    change condition
return that
```

For your specific example:

```
def check(onen, twon, threen, fourn, fiven):
    while not ((onen != twon) and (onen != threen) and (onen != fourn) and (onen != fiven)):
        onen = random.randint(1,45)
    return onen
```

Or shorter:

```
def check(onen, twon, threen, fourn, fiven):
    while onen in (twon, threen, fourn, fiven):
        onen = random.randint(1,45)
    return onen
```

Or *much* shorter, without the loop (only feasible for small range, though):

```
def check(onen, twon, threen, fourn, fiven):
    return random.choice([x for x in range(1, 46) 
                          if x not in (twon, threen, fourn, fiven)])
```

Note, however, that neither of those will change the value of `onen` outside of the function (unless, of course, you do `onen = check(...)`).

Comment: Addendum: I got the meaning of the condition backwards myself. Please check my update. General principle remains the same, though.

Answer (score 1):

What you are basically looking for is a do-while loop. Python has no do-while loop, but you can easily emulate one:

```
def something():
    while True:
        # ...
        # perform some task
        if [condition]:
            return [result]
```

So here you have to fill in `[condition]` that checks if the result is satisfying, and `[result]` is what you want to return. As long as the condition is not met, Python will go for another loop.

**Example**:

Say you want to query the user for input, you can do this with:

```
def something():
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input('Enter a number'))
        except ValueError:
            x = None

        if x is not None:
            return x
```

So here we will keep querying for a number until it is a valid one.

Of course we sometimes can fold the task and condition check together. Here we can transform the above program into:

```
def something():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input('Enter a number'))
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

From the update to your question it seems you just need to invert the sense of the while to get what you want:

```
def condition(onen, twon, threen, fourn, fiven):
    return ((onen != twon) and (onen != threen) and (onen != fourn) and (onen != fiven))

def check(onen, twon, threen, fourn, fiven):
    while not condition(onen, twon, threen, fourn, fiven):
        onen = random.randint(1,45)
    return onen
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:

```
something(condition):
    # evaluate and return condition value
while(condition is not satisfactory):
    condition = something(condition)
else:
 # code post satisfaction of condition
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def something(): 
    while(condition): 
        return that 
    else: 
        return this
        something() # just callback the function
```

You can also remove the else statment and just callback the current function

Comment: something won't be called as it's after `return` statement

Comment: But this will result in pushing on to the call stack. As a result if the condition is not easily met, we can run into a *StackOverflow* exception.